# File extension not hiding

Tags: finder, macos, dmg, file-extensions

I have a `.dmg` file and I want to hide its extension. So I do the usual and `⌘I`, then check `Hide extension`. `killall Finder` just to be sure. I look and sure enough... the file extension is still there. So I use `SetFile -a E myfile.dmg` hoping that will work. It doesn't. Any ideas? Here's a picture just in case.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the issue. Apparently two options have to be set in order for any extension to disappear (except for `.app`). First you have to go into Finder's `Preferences > Advanced`. Untick `Show all filename extensions`. Then you tick `Hide extension` in the `Get Info` window for your file and the extension is hidden.

Comment: Works for me (under MacOS Sierra).

Answer (score 0):

That's the "get info" window and not the Finder. The get info window will (in my experience) always show the extension.

Hiding the extension is for *Finder views* not the get info window.

Comment: I'm aware. I'm just showing my Get Info options in case I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing the basic thing by pressing `enter` and deleting the extension. The press `get info` to make sure the extension is still there.

Works on 10.11.4
*Tested on OSX El Capitan 10.11.4*

[image]

Comment: If you mean press `Enter` in regular Finder and then manually delete the extension, I tried that and it removes the extension entirely, as in it changes the file type from `Disk Image` to `Raw Disk Image` and doesn't show an extension in Get Info. Or maybe I'm not understanding your answer. :)

Comment: Thats funny, i did that and it stayed as a dmg but the extension was deleted from the filename. What version of osx are you using?

Comment: I'm using El Capitan.

Comment: thats what im using and it worked. Hmm im kinda lost here

Comment: Here's exactly what I'm doing as per your instructions. Go into Finder. Select my `.dmg`. Press enter (edit the filename), and press backspace until `.dmg` is gone. Then it gives me a warning popup.

Comment: Whats the warning you get?

Comment: `Are you sure you want to remove the extension “.dmg”? If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.` with `Cancel` and `Remove` as the options.

Comment: Look at this article see if it helps https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19072?locale=en_US

Comment: Im sorry if i cant help you, i tried my instructions and it worked. Do you have anything that could interfere. Filevault (i dont know, just brainstorming)

Comment: Not that I know of.